# Making Twilio outbound calls using Jersey REST client

Tags: twilio-api, jersey-client

I am trying to make outbound calls using Twilio in my Java Spring MVC Web application. I have passed the required Authorisation values and the form data required for making the outbound call, but getting an HTTP  400 error.
Now when I try to POST using Postman REST client, I am able to make the outbound call using Twilio. But the same does not work when I use my program to initiate the call. The post I use is as follows:

```
 ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
                  Client client = Client.create(config);
                  client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN));
                  WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACfeea72833464fc8711f48a0fd/Calls.json");
                  ClientResponse responseMsg = webResource
                          .queryParam("From", from)
                            .queryParam("To", to)
                            .queryParam("Url", fileUrl)
                            .queryParam("Method", "GET")
                            .queryParam("StatusCallback", "https://www.myapp.com/events")
                            .queryParam("StatusCallbackMethod", "POST")
                            .post(ClientResponse.class);
```

I get HTTP status 400 in my response. The same works when I try using postman REST client. How can I fix the issue?

The postman post is shown below:

[image: Authorization username and password]

[image: Body]

How can I make the same POST using Jersey REST client?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using an older version of the Jersey libraries 1.1x. This is they way I have implemented it using the Jersey 1.19 Client. Instead of using queryParams, I build up a MultivaluedMap with the form data they want.

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN));

WebResource webResource = client.resource("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACxxxxxxxxxxx/Calls.json");

MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
formData.add("From", "+xxxxxxxxxx");
formData.add("To", "+xxxxxxxxxx");
formData.add("Body", "This is a test");

ClientResponse responseMsg = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class, formData);
```